# Java - IntelliJ - JList in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, awt, jscrollpane, jlist

**Hello,**

**My first question on SOF. 
I've got problem with JScrollPane and JList.
I've made class for list with getter to get list object**

```
package frontend;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GeneratedList
{
    private JList<String> List;

    public GeneratedList() {
        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        listModel.addElement("1");
        List = new JList<>(listModel);
}

    public JList<String> getList() {
        return List;
    }}
```

**And got class GUI for make whole frame.**

```
package frontend;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("QR Generator");

    BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
    public static JFormattedTextField inputField = new JFormattedTextField("XX.XXXX.XX");
    JButton generateButtton = new JButton("Generate");
    JButton printButton = new JButton("Print");

    public GUI()
    {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(borderLayout);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        frame.add(inputField,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(generateButtton,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.add(printButton,BorderLayout.EAST);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setSize(200,300);
        frame.add(scrollPane.add(new GeneratedList().getList()));
    }}
```

**In this style of code it works. List is visible but there is no scrollbars**

[frame view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d43K5.jpg)

**First question is why ? :)
And second question is why in this syntax, list isn't visible on frame.**

```
package frontend;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("QR Generator");

    BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
    public static JFormattedTextField inputField = new JFormattedTextField("XX.XXXX.XX");
    JButton generateButtton = new JButton("Generate");
    JButton printButton = new JButton("Print");
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    public GUI()
    {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(borderLayout);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        frame.add(inputField,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(generateButtton,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.add(printButton,BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.add(new GeneratedList().getList());
    }
}
```

**Thanks for help**

Comment: I've edit frame.add(scrollPane);  to  frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.WEST); and it gave same result

Comment: Don't add the list to the scroll pane, add it to the view port (of the scroll pane). Having said that, I always pass the list in the constructor, so it's automatically added using the correct method. ***"And second question.."*** Don't mash questions together. Start a separate thread devoted to each question.

Comment: And don't shout. *My first question on SOF* - Do you see other questions where all the text is bold? Learn by example. That applies not only to programming but asking questions as well.

Comment: I've write this and still no scrollbars.                                                       
     ```JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        GeneratedList list = new GeneratedList();
        frame.add(scrollPane.getViewport().add(list.getList()));```

Comment: @camickr ... sorry i think that bold part will be more readable between code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame.add(scrollPane.getViewport().add(list.getList())
```

That is not how you add a component to the viewport.

You use:

```
frame.add(scrollPane.setViewportView(...);
```

Or, even easier is to add the component when you create the JScrollPane.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(...);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and a working example.

Download the example and use it as a starting point. The code from the tutorial will show you how to better structure you class.